# EF Core 7 - how to set up multiple nullable GUID foreign keys on child object without triggering foreign key conflict

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, ef-core-7.0

I have 3 entities: `Person`, `User`, and `Location`.

- A `Person` can have multiple `Locations`
- A `User` can have multiple `Locations`

My entities are set up as such:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Location>? Locations { get; set; }
}

public class PersonEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasMany(b => b.Locations)
            .WithOne(b => b.Person)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.PersonId)
            .IsRequired(false);
    }
}



public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? Username { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Location>? Locations { get; set; }
}

public class UserEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasMany(b => b.Locations)
            .WithOne(b => b.User)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.UserId)
            .IsRequired(false);
    }
}



public class Location : UdbObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Person))]
    public Guid? PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person? Person { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User? User { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem:** I tried to insert a `User` into my SQL Server DB. This user has one `Location` object within its `IList<Location>? Locations` collection. I am getting the following error: `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Locations_Persons_PersonId".`

**Here is where it is going wrong:**
Since `Person.Id` is a `Guid?` object, it automatically gets set to the equivalent of `Guid.Empty` before it is submitted to the DB. This causes the FK conflict, since the DB sees that there is no `Person` object in the DB with an Id set to the equivalent of `Guid.Empty`.

**What I've tried:** I saw that in previous version of EF Core, there is a `.WithOptional()` method that can be used in the Fluent API, but unfortunately this method is not recognized in EF Core 7. I tried to use the `.IsRequired(false)` method in the API, and it probably works from the DB standpoint, but my problem is that the GUID-based `Id` property is being set to `Guid.Empty` on the server before being passed to the DB, so `.IsRequired(false)` doesn't have the opportunity to do its job.

Am I missing something? Is there some other way to configure this?

**Solution**: I had a `PersonDto` that had a property `public Guid Id { get; set; }` instead of `Guid?` and it was being mapped back to the `Person` object with `Guid.Empty` loaded in it. Duh.

Comment: The default for a `Guid?` should be null, not `Guid.Empty`. Are you sure it's not being set somewhere, via a constructor or something?

Comment: @ESG bingo. I had a PersonDto that had a property `public Guid Id { get; set; }` instead of `Guid?` and it was being mapped back to the `Person` object with `Guid.Empty` loaded in it. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

Just make them M2M relationships and the foreign keys will all be in bridge tables.  eg

```
public class Location : UdbObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; } = new HashSet<Person>();

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; } = new HashSet<User>();
}
```